# Adding registry key via GPO creates but not affects to the system?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-registry

I could not give a **detailed** title to my question. But my problem is: I'm trying to add keyboard languages from Group Policy (Windows Server 2012R2) with Registry. I added like below:

[image]

Then I check (as a domain user), the **key is created** in Registry:

[image]

but **not visible in the taskbar**:

[image]

What could be the problem (or how can I solve the problem) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to name it "3" in your case, "1" for default.

Find more information in Esa Jokinens answer on [this Post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052587/how-to-add-new-keyboard-language-from-gpo).

And also consider setting it in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.